# Where are set cmake compilation option for C_FLAGS after executing?

Tags: gcc, cmake, makefile

I have a c/cpp project.
I was previously using a single-configuration build (with only release configuration) and I have started to add a multi-configuration build with the configurations Release and Debug.

I want to be able to do `make DEBUG=1 all` in my project with compilator options:

```
-DDEBUG -ggdb3 -O0
```

So I have use this in my CMake configure command:

```
-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG="-DDEBUG -ggdb3 -O0"
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG="-DDEBUG -ggdb3 -O0"
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug"
```

When I type the CMake command to generate the makefiles, my options are not added in the Makefile for my project. I am not able to find "-DDEBUG -ggdb3 -O0" in cmake generated files.

Where does CMake add configuration flags option?

Answer (score 0):

For your `DEBUG=1` macro definition, you need to use [`target_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html) and [the `$<CONFIG:cfgs>` generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#configuration-expressions) like so:

```
target_compile_definitions(my_target PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:DEBUG=1>")
```

For your others, `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG="-ggdb3 -O0"` on the commandline should work, and is not a bad way of doing it. You could also use [`list(APPEND)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html#modification) and a generator expression or `if()` block to only add it for the relevant compiler.